# How to find max value of Item2 in Tuple<string, DateTime>

Tags: c#

Okay, I've done this before, but I'm drawing a blank, so I'm hoping the big brains here on SO can bail me out.

I have a `Tuple<string, DateTime>` where the string is a FileName and the DateTime is the last date that file was sent by a process.  The FileNames will not be identical, but they all confirm to a filemask of some kind (for instance, I might have several entries where the `string` conforms to file mask `"????AD??"`).  I want to find the most recent `DateTime` for a given filemask.

I can't remember how I resolved this problem before, and it was at a previous employer, so I can't even cannibalize my old code.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Clarification (since this could be a little obtuse)

Given:

```
(0501AD01, 5/2/2010)
(0502AD02, 5/3/2010)
(0503AD03, 5/4/2010)
<snip>
(0803AD99, 8/4/2010)
(0804AD00, 8/5/2010)
(0805AD01, 8/6/2010)
```

I want to return `8/6/2010`

Comment: Which part do you need help with - matching the file mask or finding the max across your collection?

Comment: finding the max.  I've got the file mask.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So you have `tuples` is a `IEnumerable<Tuple<string, DateTime>>` and you have a `fileMask`, and you have a method

```
bool MatchesFileMask(FileMask fileMask, string filename)
```

that returns `true` if `filename` matches the file mask `fileMask`. Then you can say:

```
var mostRecent = tuples.Where(x => MatchesFileMask(fileMask, x.Item1)
                       .Max(x => x.Item2);
```

Answer (score 6):

Piece of cake with LINQ:

```
var data = new List<Tuple<string, DateTime>>(); // add some data

var maxTimestamp = data.Where(t => MatchesFileMask(t.Item1)).Max(t => t.Item2);
```

Of course I cheated by assuming there's a `MatchesFileMask` predicate already written, but it's not too hard to make a regex out of a simple glob-style mask:

```
var mask = "????AD??";
var regex = new Regex(mask.Replace('?', '.').Replace("*", ".*"));
var predicate = new Func<string, bool>(regex.IsMatch);

var maxTimestamp = data.Where(t => predicate(t.Item1)).Max(t => t.Item2);
```

Comment: I'd select both of these as correct if I could, but I only get one, and Jason's is a little closer to what I need for my specific solution.  Up-voted all the same.